# Writing replacement for xscreensaver

Tags: lubuntu, screensaver

I am trying to write a replacement for xscreensaver (in wxPHP, for learning purposes).  xscreensaver itself has the triggering and unlocking features, and then a library of screensavers apps to call. All very modular, which is fine for generalised software, but it has loads of overheads.

I left the trickiest bit till last - the triggering, based on time of no activity.  I was hoping that there would be something (perhaps a time field in ~/.xscreensaver ) that I could simply pick up and use, but there doesn't seem to be anything.

I guess something at the session level must be keeping track of all the activity going on, but where is the time of last activity?

Using Lubuntu 16.04

Comment: If you don't mind using an external command for this, `xprintidle` returns the idle time in seconds. You can probably check its source to see how it does that.

Comment: You do need to install the xprintidle package as it is not installed by default in lubuntu.

Comment: Thank you, that's just what I needed.  Curiously, when run from the PHP script, it returns in milliseconds, but when run from a terminal it returns a small value always <= 10